# How to centralize I18n messages

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Similar to we have `spring-cloud-config` for centralizing configuration, do we have something for centralizing i18n `messages.properties`? What would be the best way to do so?

Comment: Config server can serve plain text files: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-config.adoc#serving-plain-text and I think you can configure messagesources to use url's as sources.